# disable Rubocop complaint about method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I have a method that goes like this `return if amount == 0` and rubocop is complaining that it should be like `return if amount.zero?`. How can I have it skip over that method? Here is my .rubocop.yml:

**rubocop**

```
StringLiterals:
  EnforcedStyle: double_quotes
  Enabled: true

Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Enabled: false

Style/TrailingCommaInLiteral:
  Enabled: false

Style/TrailingCommaInArguments:
  Enabled: false

Style/CaseEquality:
  Enabled: false

Documentation:
  Description: "Document classes and non-namespace modules."
  Enabled: false

Metrics/MethodLength:
  CountComments: false
  Max: 15

Rails/Delegate:
  Enabled: false

AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - db/**/*
    - config/**/*
    - script/**/*
    - vendor/**/*
    - bin/**/*
    - Rakefile
    - spec/spec_helper.rb
    - spec/rails_helper.rb
    - spec/teaspoon_env.rb

  TargetRubyVersion: 2.3

Rails:
  Enabled: true
```

**submit_ticket_payment.rb**

```
def call
  return if amount == 0
  Stripe::Charge.create(
    amount: amount,
    currency: "usd",
    description: event_name,
    receipt_email: context.rsvp.email,
    source: context.token,
    statement_descriptor: event_name
  )
rescue Stripe::StripeError
  context.fail!
end
```

So basically how can I have it not care about that particular instance?

Comment: Silly question, but why not follow it's suggestion?

Comment: `zero?` method will return if the expectation is truthy, I like the explicit nature of `== 0` more.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The check in question is implemented by the [`Style/NumericPredicate`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/NumericPredicate) cop.

If you generally want it to be enabled but not complain about an individual occurence, you can temporarily disable it with a special comment:

```
# rubocop:disable Style/NumericPredicate
return if amount == 0
# rubocop:enable Style/NumericPredicate
```

Note that it needs to be enabled again; otherwise it will skip the check for the whole remainder of the file.

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to skip rule only for this particular method then:

```
# rubocop:disable Style/NumericPredicate
def call
  return if amount == 0
  # ...
end
# rubocop:enable Style/NumericPredicate
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can either ignore the rule or try to refactor the code to be complaint, which is usual a better practice.

For the first option, ignoring the rule, apart from the cases already mentioned there is also:

Inline ignore with special comment:

```rb
def call
  return if amount == 0 # rubocop:disable Style/NumericPredicate
  # ...
end
```

And ignore in config file which is usual a better option, this way you have all your styles configuration in one place. You can use either the `.rubocop.yml` or the `.rubocop_todo.yml`, the purpose of the latter is to list all offenses, but work on refactoring to remove them one by one. The todo file can be generated with the CLI command `rubocop --auto-gen-config`.

```yaml
Style/NumericPredicate:
  Exclude:
    - 'path/to/file.rb'
```

Now about refactoring, I understand the question is not about that, but I feel it is always good to mention. We all know what happens when we take the easy path of ignoring rules! :)

In this case let's suppose you can get in the `amount` variable either `0` or `nil`, for the condition to be met. The problem is that if you call `nil.zero?`, it will raise `NoMethodError: undefined method` zero?' for nil:NilClass`, what you can do here is use the [Safe Navigation Operator](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+Navigation+Operator):

`&.`

so your code could look something like this.

```rb
def call
  return if amount&.zero? || amount.nil?
  # ...
end
```